# Displaying an error when a user tries to submit an angular form that isn't completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working with an Angular form where the user clicks "Next Step" and the next portion of the form shows up. However, I have it so that the next step button is disabled until all fields are valid.

My question is, how can I add a class I've made to highlight the field that's not completed when the user clicks the next step button? Should I use $scope.watch or is there an easier way to root out the source of the invalid form?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question correctly, the documentation has a good example of what you are trying to accomplish: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

there a message is displayed if the field is empty

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
```